# Can't get my Mac App signed for testing receipt validation

Tags: xcode, cocoa, code-signing

I have my "Mac Developer: ..." certificate installed and it is valid.
I have the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations intermediate ceritficate as well.
I also have a "3rd Party Mac Developer Application" distribution certificate.

In my build settings I have chosen my "Mac Developer: ..." identity for code-signing. 
When I built the first time, codesign asked for permission to sign my app and I clicked Always Allow.

Then I did a "Show in Finder.." to see the Product of the build. I found my .app and double clicked it. However, this is what is shown in the system Console:

```
10/13/11 8:40:44.531 PM storeagent: Unsigned app (/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAppName-gabpxiaypxtnikelsyzjwkperixq/Build/Products/Debug/MyAppName.app).
```

I'm not running the app from Xcode, I just opened the Console app and then double-clicked the app in my build directory.

Why is my app still unsigned? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a long time to figure out what was causing this when I had the same issue myself a while back.  I finally figured it out.  You **must** set the `Code Signing Identity` (in your app's target & project settings) to `3rd Party mac Developer Application`.  Then, when exporting your app you must select the `3rd Party Mac Developer Installer` certificate in the export wizard.

That's the only way that worked for me.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yep. I had two problems. For some reason the 3rd party cert wouldn't properly install in Xcode so I couldn't choose that one in the Code Signing build settings. I deleted all of my certs, revoked them in iTunes Provisioning center, regenerated and reinstall them. THEN I was able to choose the 3rd party cert and it's signing properly now.

Answer (score 2):

What works for me everytime is killing the storeagent (thanks fubo). For me it only works with exact that command:

```
killall -KILL storeagent
```